# Como obtener la id auto incremental de una fila que se acaba de crear - SQL

Tags: javascript, php, sql

Tengo una tabla **usuario** con una columna **id** que es auto incremental, y una tabla **imágenes** que tiene esta **id** como llave foránea.
Con una pagina *php* cargo los datos de la tabla **usuario** y las imágenes de la tabla **imágenes**, en esa misma pagina.

Mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo obtener la id para ponerla con las imágenes?. Estaba pensando en hacer la consulta buscando por el nombre o las otras columnas de la tabla usuario, pero siento que no es lo correcto.

> ***USUARIO***: Id_usuario, Nombre_usuario, Apellido_usuario, Correo_usuario, Teléfono_usuario.

> ***IMÁGENES***: Id_imagen, Nombre_imagen, Dirección_imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa la función [mysqli_insert_id](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php) o [PDO::lastInsertId](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.lastinsertid.php) según sea tu caso.

```php
$query = "INSERT INTO myCity VALUES (NULL, 'Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Stuttgart', 617000)";
$mysqli->query($query);
echo 'Nuevo registro con el id => '.$mysqli->insert_id;




$consulta=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tblanuncios(Anun_Registrado) VALUES (:Anun_Registrado)");
$consulta -> bindParam(":Anun_Registrado", $Anun_Registrado, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$lastInsertId = $pdo->lastInsertId();
echo 'Nuevo registro con el id => '.$lastInsertId;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no conocía esta función.